# Typescript discriminated union types with Rx.js filter operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Typescript supports [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html). **How to extend the same concept with Rxjs to the `filter` operator** in below example?

```
interface Square {
    kind: 'square';
    width: number;
}

interface Circle {
    kind: 'circle';
    radius: number;
}

interface Center {
    kind: 'center';
}

type Shape = Square | Circle | Center;

const obs$: Observable<Shape> = of<Shape>({ kind: 'square', width: 10 });

// Expected type: Observable<Square>
// Actual type: Observable<Shape>
const newObs$ = obs$.pipe(
    filter((x) => x.kind === 'square')
);
```

I above code snippet, I would want to see newObs$ to have its type inferred as: `Observable<Square>`. But apparently, `TypeScript` doesn't do that.

**How to achieve this? Am I reaching the limits of TypeScript type inference?**

*I look for this as it seems to be very useful in a `Redux + Redux-Observable` codebase.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you can do this with TypeScript type guards. See section "Type Guards and Differentiating Types" at http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

The key here is the `function isWhatever(x: any): x is Whatever => ...` syntax.

This basically says that if the `isWhatever` function returns `true` then it guarantees that `x` is of `Whatever` type.

In your example TypeScript considers all three classes:

[image: without-typeguard]

So you can define the predicate function for `filter()` as this:

```
filter((x: Shape): x is Square => x.kind === 'square')
```

Now it will properly consider only the `Square` class:

[image: with-typeguard]

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-z9lwxe?file=index.ts

Very similar question: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2340

Comment: Yes. This seems to solve the problem. However, it is still verbose. I am still looking if by some means automatic type inference can work so that I won't have to manually specify the type. For now, it seems like unreasonable expectation from TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a limitation with the TypeScript type system but rather with the implementation of `filter`. You can easily achieve the desired behaviour using `flatMap`:

```
// Inferred type: Observable<Square>
const newObs$ = obs$.pipe(
  flatMap((x) => x.kind === "square" ? of(x) : empty())
);
```